# A long winding road

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

Start at the mountain of kings
Then go down the country to face the oldest rivals.
Go on down through the bizarre,
And you'll find the place that cuts.
Go a hundred miles southeast to find birds,
Then leave to see those who last fought metal in the end.
Go North, passing the one above
To end where the lightning strikes.
Go North west one border over to find two types of planes,
Then seek their recent enemies for the grey.
From there, go south less than a two hundred miles.

What's the weather there, and what was your path?

Comment: Put two spaces at the end of the line to get the newline to work

Comment: @GordonAllocman Fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start at the mountain of kings

> Montreal - which means something like royal mountain

Then go down the country to face the oldest rivals.

> Toronto - Ice hockey rivalry between Montreal and Toronto is the oldest as per Wikipedia

Go on down through the bizarre,

> Lake Erie - pronounced eerie, which means bizarre

And you'll find the place that cuts.

> Cleveland - cleave

Go a hundred miles southeast to find birds,

> Pittsburgh - Pittsburgh penguins hockey team

Then leave to see those who last fought metal in the end.

> Green Bay, WI - won the super bowl against Pittsburgh Steelers

Go North, passing the one above

> Lake Superior - Superiors are above you

To end where the lightning strikes.

> Thunder Bay, ON

Go North west one border over to find two types of planes

> Winnipeg - Winnipeg Jets (hockey) and Winnipeg Blue Bombers (football)

Then seek their recent enemies for the grey. (Thanks to f'')

> Vancouver - Winnipeg was against Vancouver in 2011 in Grey Cup

From there, go south less than a two hundred miles

> Seattle

What's the weather there

> [Seattle Weather](https://www.google.com/search?q=seattle+weather&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) or stormy (Seattle Storm basketball) or cloudy, because when is Seattle not cloudy

Comment: You're up to a good start!

Comment: @Seraviel The next clue is pretty broad, though...

Comment: @question_asker I think there's just more riddle like references, not ciphers. I just googled all the NHL team names, and there seem to be a couple more hockey references.

Comment: @Munir no no, I was just putting things in ROT13 to keep them from being spoiled for anybody trying to work out the puzzle on their own - I think it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @question_asker sorry...misunderstood what you were trying to do. I have some work to do, but will get back to this in another 30-40 mins.

Comment: Maybe Tampa Bay Lightning is the next?

Comment: @hyst329 I thought so too...but Tampa is in the south, and the line just above it is go north.

Comment: @Munir Nice work! I'd be surprised if this isn't the answer!

Comment: Very close, but you're missing a little detail in the end. Think about the general subject, and you'll find it.

Comment: @Seraviel yeah i know...wanted to have a bit of fun before I put that in. :)

Comment: The Seattle Storm was what I was looking for, yes.